# Disallow tag by context in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I would like to allow `h1` tags but not inside a list. For example, valid code would be `<h1>Title</h1><ul><li>Item 1</li></ul>`. Invalid code would be `<ul><li><h1>Item 1</h1></li></ul>`.

Is it this possible? ACF seems to be related to tags independently of context, if I am right. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: I don't think this can be done via the editor itself, but you could always validate the content before saving it in your storage.

Comment: Yes of course but I want to keep the visual feedback (i.e. graying out the H1 button when the selection is inside the list).